# How to install Pillow on termux?

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, termux

I am using Termux for quite a while now and would like to install "Pillow" library on it. Whenever I try to install Pillow using "pip" it shows me the below errors.
At first I thought I need to upgrade pip, but it did not help. I have also cleared caches, to no avail.

**Error**

```
$ python3 -m pip install Pillow==7.2.0          Collecting Pillow==7.2.0                          Using cached Pillow-7.2.0.tar.gz (39.1 MB)    Using legacy setup.py install for Pillow, since package 'wheel' is not installed.               Installing collected packages: Pillow               Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error                                                   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:                                                   command: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-48geu0sg/Pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-48geu0sg/Pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-record-rstq_guv/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.8/Pillow                   cwd: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-48geu0sg/Pillow/                      Complete output (172 lines):                    running install                                 running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.8/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
    writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext


    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-48geu0sg/Pillow/setup.py", line 864, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-48geu0sg/Pillow/setup.py", line 694, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-48geu0sg/Pillow/setup.py", line 918, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-48geu0sg/Pillow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-48geu0sg/Pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-record-rstq_guv/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.8/Pillow Check the logs for full command output.
```

How do I install Pillow on termux?

Comment: It tells you what the problem is, and where to get more information: "The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source. Please see the install instructions at https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html"

Comment: @CrazyChucky bro i checked internet and all other things but can't got any help... I think this is asking for zlib that is currently unavailable in termux so how to solve it ??

Comment: zlib is for png, libjpeg is for jpeg. Both are required by default, but you can force Pillow to not require either or both, *as explained in the linked installation instructions*.

Comment: The linked instructions say that if you can't install libjpeg, you'll need to build Pillow with the `--disable-jpeg` flag.

Comment: On the other hand, if you DO have a library installed and pip can't find it, it might just be looking in the wrong place for your header files: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1957 (This was the first hit when Googling "pillow termux".)

Comment: https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Image_Editors#Python

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First download the `wheel` module from pypi

```
pip install wheel
```

Then install the `libjpeg-turbo` package.

```
pkg install libjpeg-turbo
```

And now install `Pillow` with:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/system/lib/" CFLAGS="-I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/" pip install Pillow
```

**Note:** If you are using an aarch64 device, set the `LDFLAGS` flag to `"-L/system/lib64/"`

related: [Install Pillow in termux - Termux Wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Image_Editors#Python)

Comment: Wow... Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi. Which version of `Pillow` have you installed?
When I'm trying to install it I'm getting errors like:
`ld.lld: error: /system/lib/libdl.so is incompatible with aarch64linux`;
`ld.lld: error: /system/lib/libc.so is incompatible with aarch64linux`;
`ld.lld: error: /system/lib/libdl.so is incompatible with aarch64linux`;
`

Comment: Same error as @Koli96 any solution ?

Comment: @Catfoxes try `LDFLAGS="-L/system/lib64/" CFLAGS="-I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/" pip install Pillow`

Comment: Yes, it works on `aarch64` based devices.

Comment: After doing the first two steps, it worked, no need for the third step. Installed Pillow regularly after that (from requirements.txt file).

Answer (score 0):

```
pkg install -y python ndk-sysroot clang make \ libjpeg-turbo
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.